# mongoose how to calculate field percentage

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

The problem is not easy to describe, here are the simple expectations

```
{
  "a": "any value",
  "b": "any value",
  "c": "any value",
  "d": "any value",
  "e": "any value",
  "percent": 1
},
{
  "a": "any value",
  "b": "any value",
  "c": "any value",
  "d": "any value",
  "e": "", // "", null, []
  "percent": 0.8
},
{
  "a": "any value",
  "b": "any value",
  "c": "any value",
  "d": "", // "", null, []
  "e": "", // "", null, []
  "percent": 0.6
}
```

Just like the result above, the `percent` is derived from the valid fields of the document.

Can run online here https://mongoplayground.net/p/-4ErArICrgK

How should i achieve it, Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.coll.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "percent": {
      "$divide": [
        { "$size": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" },
            "cond": {
              "$not": [
                {
                  "$in": [
                    "$$this.v",
                    [ "", null, [] ]
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }},
        {
          "$size": {
            "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ak5KdCzoXS4)

Comment: What if the field is not "" but is null, or [] ？

Comment: @nlineBGO You should have first mentioned this in the question or should have shown some  document with that condition.